# Get beautified URL from HttpServletRequest

Tags: servlets, servlet-filters, omnifaces, prettyfaces

I am using the `org.omnifaces.filter.HttpFilter` to redirect visitors on login page when nobody is logged in.

```
@Override
public void doFilter(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res, HttpSession session, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String loginUrl = "/myapp/login?redirect_url=" + req.getRequestURL();
    boolean loggedIn = (req.getRemoteUser() != null);
    if (loggedIn) {
        chain.doFilter(req, res); // So, just continue request.
    } else {
        Servlets.facesRedirect(req, res, loginUrl);
    }
}
```

I want to redirect **not logged in** users to `/login?redirect_url=previous_page_url`

The problem is that all my URLs are beautified by **pretty-faces** and when I try to get the previous URL with `HttpServletRequest.getRequestURI()`, it gives me the ugly URL.

For example, I configured an url `/myapp/my-page-3` which displays `/views/module1/page3.xhtml`.

But `HttpServletRequest.getRequestURI()` is giving me `/views/module1/page3.xhtml` and **not** `/myapp/my-page-3`.

Any ideas ?

Comment: As you're already using OmniFaces .. Does `Servlets.getRequestURI(req)` return the expected URI?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the servlet based URL rewrite engine uses under the covers `RequestDispatcher#forward()` to forward an incoming friendly-URL request to the desired resource, then you can use `request.getAttribute(RequestDispatcher.FORWARD_REQUEST_URI)` to find out the original request URI.

```
String originalRequestURI = request.getAttribute(RequestDispatcher.FORWARD_REQUEST_URI);
```

As you're already using OmniFaces, you can use `Servlets#getRequestURI()` to automatically detect it and return it when present, else fall back to the default `HttpServletRequest#getRequestURI()`.

```
String requestURI = Servlets.getRequestURI(request);
```